# Messaging App Data Design Not efficient enough

Tags: database, data-structures, database-design, architecture, messaging

Im working on a database with the following tables.

**Table Message**
————————
Id -
Body -
Sender -
Receiver -
IsSeen (boolean)

**Table Room**
——————-
Id -
Name

**Table participants**
——————-
RoomID (foreign key from Room.Id) -
UserId (foreign key from user.id)

**Table User**
——————
Id -
Name

If someone messages in a groupchat ( a room with more than 2 participants) and I want to know who in that groupchat has seen the message, I need to insert that same message for each users in that group chat.
In group chats, `Message.Receiver`=`Room.Id` And `Message.Sender`=`User.Id`. Is this data structure efficient? Is there a better way of doing this?
Imagine in a group chat of 50 people, every single message sent adds 50 rows to the database! That's where I think this data structure is lacking

Answer (score 0):

Calling all of your ID fields ID is confusing to readers.

Your Message table should just hold a message.

```
Message
-------
Message ID
Message text
Message timestamp
```

Since you have a many to many relationship between users and messages, you create a junction table.

```
UserMessage
-----------
UserMessage ID (PK)
User ID
Message ID
Sender flag (Sender, Receiver)
Seen flag
```

Where the UserMessage ID is the primary clustering key, and you have a unique index on (User ID, Message ID).  You can also have a unique index on (Message ID, User ID).  The Sender flag is a boolean that tells you whether or not the User ID is from the sender or one of the receivers.  The Seen flag indicates whether a receiver has seen the message or not.  It's assumed that the sender has seen the message.

In your 50 person group chat, you'd have one message row and 51 user-message rows.  The UserMesssage table is 3 integers and 2 booleans, for a total of 14 bytes.  Even with 3 indexes, you're probably using less than 50 bytes per row.